# Newest questions not updating

Tags: bug, status-completed, question-lists, newest-questions

The "newest" question tab does not appear to be updating SO, Meta, or any other site. When a new question is posted the notification bar appears and when I click on it, the new question appears in the list as expected, but if I refresh the page, it disappears again. At first I thought this was a temporary issue, but it appears fairly persistent.

Here's some screenshots to illustrate. Notice the time stamps:
[image]
[image]

My setup:

- Windows 7 SP 1
- Google Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m